# Secret to long-lasting relationship: Shut Down or Close Lid?

Tags: mac, sleep-wake, shutdown, macbook-pro

The guy at the Apple store was like: "I just close the lid, and that works fine *for me*. I also shut it down every 1 (or 2) weeks, to clear the RAM".

That makes sense, *but* it sounds like his *personal experience*. Is there anything **official/unwritten law** on what we should do when we are done with our Macs, at night for example.

I am a person that almost accesses the laptop (MacBook pro 15'' Retina) every day. It's brand new and I wish for a *long-lasting relationship* with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the software level his advice should be fine. The only difference could be battery life. Hibernation still consumes a tiny bit of energy and is therefore using the battery. Shutting it down completely should make your battery last a little longer which means that you're using slightly less recharge cycles. But let's be honest, the difference is near to zero - so don't worry about it. His advice should be fine.

A bigger concern should be your screen. If you clean it too often the reflective coating is going to get ruined. And if you don't use a keyboard cover you can ruined your screen/coating too.

Comment: I think you should either edit your answer to cite evidence that cleaning the screen too often ruins the reflective coating as well as the keyboard cover or remove those sentences entirely. - From Review -